# Which one is correct — "facades weathering all weathers" or "facade weathering all weathers"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

[image: Facades weathering all weathers]

On my website banner, I had a sentence that read "Facade finishes weathering all weathers". Somebody suggested to me to change it to "Facades weathering all weathers", stating that when action (*finishes*) is removed from the sentence, we need to make the *facade* plural.

So which one is correct?

> 1. Facades weathering all weathers.
> 2. Facade weathering all weathers.

Comment: What happened to *finishes*? How is it "an action"? What are you actually trying to say?

Comment: Fragments of sentences mean virtually nothing, especially when *finishes* might be a verb or a noun. If it is a verb, how can you remove it?

Comment: Or was "finishes" mean to refer to *the finish* on a facade*? A link to you website might help us to understand, but at present, we can't answer because we don't know what you are trying to say!

Comment: What's the full context? Are you selling installation of different facades? Are you translating a web page? Give the full paragraph or context around it.

Comment: @Mitch [link](http://testinnovbuild.lumos.in/) see the second banner

Comment: This is not an advertising quality consulting site.

Comment: I would personally use "Facades _that weather_ all weathers"

Comment: You must first edit your question to match the two sentences. Remove *finishes* if that was not intended. Else this may become a NARQ.

Comment: What @Mitch said. OP's construction is just an advertising byline - it's not a complete sentence, nor does it necessarily need to be "grammatical".

Answer (score 1):

*Weathering* means

> **1** wear away or change the appearance or texture of (something) by long exposure to the atmosphere:
>      [*with object and complement*]:
>      *his skin was weathered almost black by his long outdoor life*
>      •   [*no object*] (of rock or other material) be worn away or altered by long exposure to the atmosphere:
>            *the ice sheet preserves specimens that would weather away more quickly in other regions*
>
> **2** (of a ship) come safely through (a storm):
>      *the sturdy boat had weathered the storm well*
>      •   withstand (a difficulty or danger):
>            *this year has tested industry’s ability to weather recession*
>      •   *Sailing* get to the windward of (a cape).
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/weather)

Note that the first definition involves ***wearing away,*** and the second relies on a sailing metaphor.

Far better to use ***withstand*** to make it explicit that your facades are hard-wearing and not likely to wear away.

> Facades withstanding all weathers

---

I've concentrated on this, because the part of the question asking about whether *facade* should be plural is General Reference. You are supplying facades, or facade finishes [where *facade* is an attributive noun, a noun-as-adjective] — that is the *finish*<sup>1</sup> of the facades. The main noun, whichever it is, must be plural.

<sup>1</sup> the surface appearance of a manufactured material or object, or the material used to produce this [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/finish)

Comment: I think the OP's question relates to something else altogether.

Comment: @Kris Dealt with that.